# How to remove packages listed by dpkg

Tags: dpkg

I apologise in advance: this question has probably been asked about 100 times but I can't seem to find a solution.

My problem: I'm trying to remove Qt Creator (and everything else Qt-related) from my laptop because I have been experiencing [this problem](http://hostilefork.com/2013/10/20/qtcreator-debugger-no-locals-ubuntu/) with Qt creator 2.8. Having entered the command `dpkg --get-selections | grep qt`, I get a list of about 20-30 packages. Most of these packages are listed as `install` but some are listed as either `deinstall` or `purge`. When I attempt to `apt-get purge` the packages listed as `purge` or `deinstall`, I am informed that the package in question is not installed on my system. Why are the packages still listed when I have removed them?

1) Is there a way to remove all packages containing a specific keyword (e.g. by using `grep`)?

2) Why are some packages listed as `purge` or `deinstall`? I read somewhere that the command `apt-get dselect-upgrade` will perform these operations but this but that did not work.

3) Why is dpkg giving me a list of packaged that includes packages that I have removed?

There's obviously a lot I have to learn about package management in Ubuntu, any help is appreciated.

I am using Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: 1. Yes 2. Because they are either purged or just deinstalled. 3. Because dpkg is listing it's database. Now, for the real question, can you just `sudo apt-get remove` them?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answers for 1 and 2? Yes, `apt-get remove` works but I was hoping for an easier way than having to type the name of every package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aptitude or apt-get. The problem with this is that just `qt` selects too many packages and you could very well uninstalling other stuff that shouldn't/doesn't need to be uninstalled:

```
sudo apt-get -s remove qt*
```

This won't remove any packages, but will let you see what will you be removing.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude search '?and(?name(qt), ~i)'
```

This will search any package that has qt and it's installed. Change the `search` for `remove` to remove it.

Comment: The first command you gave me outputs `Package 'packagename' is not installed, so not removed' for a long list of packages, most of which do not even contain 'qt'.
The second command gives no output at all.

Comment: If the second command (I'm guessing `aptitude search '?and(?name(qt), ~i)'`) doesn't give output, it means that you don't have any qt package installed. Congratz! You can also use `aptitude search '?and(qt, ~i, !~M)'` to broad the search.

Comment: OK so I've accomplished that task... now how do I stop dpkg listing packages that I've removed?

Comment: if you mean `dpkg --get-selections` it will show them whatever you do, since it list all package status not just the ones you have installed.

Comment: Oh, it seems I have been missing the point of `--get-selections`. Thanks for all your help.